# dynamically add a blank row to html table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code and am trying to add a blank row to the table when the date changes:

```
<?php $old_date = $crew_rows[0]["date"] ?>
<?php foreach ($crew_rows as $crew_row):?>   

<tr >
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["date"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["first"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["last"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["crew"]?></td>  
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["status"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["avalstart"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["avalend"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"colspan="2"><?=$crew_row["cell"]?></td>  
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["email"]?></td>        
</tr>         
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: can you tell me your array structure.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're VERY close...

```
<?php $old_date = $crew_rows[0]["date"] ?>
<?php foreach ($crew_rows as $crew_row):?>   

<tr >
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["date"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["first"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["last"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["crew"]?></td>  
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["status"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["avalstart"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["avalend"]?></td>
  <td style="text-align:left;"colspan="2"><?=$crew_row["cell"]?></td>  
  <td style="text-align:left;"><?=$crew_row["email"]?></td>  

</tr> 
<?php if ($old_date != $crew_row["date"]) { ?>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>   
<?php $old_date = $crew_row["date"];} ?>        
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Almost, you need to move the `if ($old_date != $crew_row["data"])` outside the `tr` and not inside it.

Comment: no, neither of those answers work.  When I add:  <?php if ($old_date != $crew_row["date"]) { print "$old_date"; ?>  the old_date prints out above the table

Comment: I replaced the code just after the foreach statement and added $old_date = $crew_row["date"] to the end of the if statement and it works.  Thanks.